An escape character exists in the value of JSON, causing a decoding error
When data is provided from the server, an escape character is included, so an error occurs when decoding into Decodable type. Even if I change it to a dictionary using JSONSerialization, an error still occurs when decoding data with an escape character.
How can I solve this problem?
let jsonStr = """
{
  "overview": "I \n love \n you."
}
"""


struct ResponseDTO: Decodable {
  let overview: String?
  
  enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case overview
  }
  
  init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.overview = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .overview)
  }
}

let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!
func task() {
  do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseDTO.self, from: jsonData)
      print(response)
  } catch {
    print("Failed to decode: \(error)")
  }
}

task()

The problem is that when trying to decode the container, an error is thrown due to the escape character. T T...
How can I decode characters with escape JSON as is?

you could just remove it, such as: let str = jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")

Well, I tried again and it worked... Thank you for letting me know :)

The problem is your attempt to simulate JSON data with a Swift string. In JSON, you can have a newline character by using the escape sequence of a backslash followed by the letter n (\n). In order to represent that sequence of two characters in a Swift string literal, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash (\\n).
In other words, change:
let jsonStr = """
{
  "overview": "I \n love \n you."
}
"""

to:
let jsonStr = """
{
  "overview": "I \\n love \\n you."
}
"""

The resulting decoded string will have actual newline characters in it.
You can also remove your explicit init from your struct.
Here is a fully working version of your code and the resulting output:
let jsonStr = """
{
  "overview": "I \\n love \\n you."
}
"""


struct ResponseDTO: Decodable {
    let overview: String?

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case overview
    }
}

let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!
func task() {
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseDTO.self, from: jsonData)
        print(response.overview ?? "")
    } catch {
        print("Failed to decode: \(error)")
    }
}

task()

When run in a Swift Playground you get:

I
 love
 you.

Also note that your use of print(response) can cause confusion because the output of the struct with the optional String property has the newline characters shown in their escaped form of \n.

ResponseDTO(overview: Optional("I \n love \n you."))

This can easily lead you to think there are literal backslash and letter n characters in the result instead of actual newline characters.

Thank you for providing detailed information.
Since the server transmits data decoded from jsonStr, I learned that escape should not be in the json value. I solved the problem of removing escapes by using replacingOccurrences, but it becomes a problem when there is a lot of data.

@sweetSwift It sounds like the server is sending bad JSON data. If the server is sending JSON with strings containing actual newline characters (#0A), then it isn't valid and needs to be fixed. It should be encoding newline characters as a slash followed by an n. No receiver of the server's JSON should have to remove newline characters from the raw JSON in order to parse it.

Aha TT.. Thanks for the advice. I converted the data type to a string and temporarily removed \n, but I found out that it's really not good if it contains newline characters haha....
